# Центрировать блок по центу при наведении на изображение

Tags: css, html5

Есть галерея, при наведении на изображение нужно чтобы оно затемнялось, и на нем по центру появлялась надпись(описание). На каждом изображении надпись будет разной длинны поэтому вариант с фиксированным положением не подходит, не получается сделать чтобы она была по центру этого изображения(margin:0 auto; не срабатывает).

```css
.overlay{
     position: relative;
     display: block;
    }
    
    
    .overlay .overlayed_text{
     display: none;
    }
    .overlay:hover .overlayed_text{
     display: block;
     background-color: #8c8c8c;
     filter: alpha(opacity=75);
     opacity: .75;
     position: absolute;
     width: 471px;
        height: 237px;
    }
    .overlayed_text span{
     display: block;
     padding-top: 30px;
        padding-bottom: 30px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
     color: #fff;
     font-weight: bold;
     border: 2px #fff solid;
     text-align: center;
     position: absolute;
    }
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
    <a href="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/powr/defaults/image-slider2.jpg" class="big">
<img src="http://www.irishcultureandcustoms.com/01News/18Surfer.jpg"  alt="" title="СТУДИЯ С ЯРКИМИ АКЦЕНТАМИ">
<div class="overlayed_text">
    <span>СТУДИЯ С ЯРКИМИ АКЦЕНТАМИ</span>
</div>
</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мыслите слоями если используете position. Но не забываете, что у родителя должен быть position: relative, чтобы position: absolute у дочернего элемента работал правильно.

```css
.big {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  display: none;
}
.big:hover > .overlay {
  display: flex;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
    background-color: #8c8c8c;
    filter: alpha(opacity=75);
    opacity: .75;
}
.overlayed_text {
  margin: auto;
}

.overlayed_text span{
    display: block;
    padding: 30px 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 2px #fff solid;
}


/* ---- без flex ---- */

.overlay2 {
  display: none;
}
.big:hover > .overlay2 {
  display: block;
}

.overlay2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
    background-color: #8c8c8c;
    filter: alpha(opacity=75);
    opacity: .75;
}
.overlayed_text2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.overlayed_text2 span{
    display: block;
    padding: 30px 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 2px #fff solid;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="big">
  <img src="http://beerhold.it/400/300">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="overlayed_text"><span>СТУДИЯ С ЯРКИМИ АКЦЕНТАМИ</span></div>
  </div>
</a>

<a href="#" class="big">
  <img src="http://beerhold.it/400/300">
  <div class="overlay2">
    <div class="overlayed_text2"><span>СТУДИЯ С ЯРКИМИ АКЦЕНТАМИ</span></div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: А есть ли вариант без использования display:flex?

Comment: Конечно. Добавил код в ответ.